# MapView not working

Tags: java, android

I Code, Google map not come on the mobile Screen please anyone help me. I have attached `MainActivity` Code, `Manifest.xml` Code and `main.xml` Code.

`MainActivity` code below :

```
public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {
    MapView mymaps;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        
        mymaps = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.maps);
    }
    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Manifest.xml** code below :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.map_test4"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

This is my `apiKey` :

```
 android:apiKey="AIzaSyB6JuQng3ru7CukjE_9osXMX1fa4SbLz9Q"
/>
```

Comment: and you have to use openGles feature for maps v1

Comment: and please sign the apk with the keystore that you have used to generate maps api key

Answer (score 0):

You have to use openGles feature for maps v1 and please sign the apk with the keystore that you have used to generate maps api key

Answer (score 0):

call your mapview as fragment using this code

```
map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            .getMap();
```

Answer (score 0):

The ApiKey needs to be placed inside the layout xml of the map-view. See here for a good example:https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/hello-mapview

Answer (score 0):

As you have said

"I have attached MainActivity Code, Manifest.xml Code and **main.xml** Code."

and you are using

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

this might also be one of the reason?  Make sure you have correct layout.

or,also  make sure u have correct debug api key for google maps and it must be inside child of .